# X-label of graph is not visible

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have imported an Excel file and want to  plot a 2D graph by using data from that file.

[image]

I have used matplotlib to plot graph by using 
`df.plot("Col1","Col2")` but its is not showing X-labels in the graph which should be `text(Col1)`

What changes should I apply to `Code()`?

Answer (score 0):

According to pandas docs your code is correct. Perhaps you can try another method of showing the x-label in order to see where the problem comes from. You can try the following

```
ax = df.plot()  # retrieve the matplotlib Axes object
ax.xlabel("Col1")  # set the x-label
ax.ylabel("Col2")  # set the y-label
```

See this docpage
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html

Comment: still not showing text labels

Comment: @TruptiChaudhari What kind of answers do you expect without providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? We cannot guess your data structure and your code.